# Does weak convergence of functions on periodic domains implies strong convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence, periodic-functions

Does weak convergence of (periodic) $L^2(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ functions imply strong convergence?

i.e. let $f_n \in L^2(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$

assume $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ in $L^2$

does $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^2$?

Intuitively, if weak convergence means that part of the 'mass' of the function travels to infinity, then the constraint of periodicity should prevent this and thus imply strong convergence, but I can't prove it. I also can't find a counterexample :(

Comment: What kinds of $L^2$ periodic functions do we have?

Comment: oops, I meant $L^2(0,T)$, I guess I should just change the question to functions $f_n (0,T) \to \mathbb{R}$